# JavaFX background-image works in scenebuilder and win but not on osx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, netbeans-7, scenebuilder

I have a simple FXML which has a background-image defined for a tab-pane in an external css-file.

The background-images is located in a image-directory which is placed in the same folder as in the .FXML

The problem is that this background-image is being displayed in SceneBuilder (Win 7 and OSX Mountain Lion) but when running the application, only on Windows 7.

I'm using Netbeans 7.2 and also tried updating to JDK 7.0_06 on OSX. I also made sure that my project is being build with 7.0_06.

```
#mainNavigation .tab-content-area,
#mainNavigation .tab {
  -fx-background-color: #dddddd;
  -fx-background-image: url('./img/tabpaneBG.png');
}
```

What else might I try?

Comment: check letter's case. Mac is case-sensitive.

Comment: That was exactly my problem -.-' Thanks a lot for that tip (: Quite irritating that it still works in SceneBuilder.