# Background Image shows in SceneBuilder but not when App runs

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Already searched for an answer for this but the only similar question I could find was here ([JavaFX background-image works in scenebuilder and win but not on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995958/javafx-background-image-works-in-scenebuilder-and-win-but-not-on-osx)) and it hasn't been answered.

I'm trying to get a background image to show when my App runs. I'm using Eclipse, JavaFX and SceneBuilder. I have applied the CSS File to my FXML file. At the minute the background image will only show in SceneBuilder.

CSS Code:

```
#background {
-fx-background-position: center;
-fx-background-color: #BDBDBD;
-fx-background-image: url('./Background.png');
-fx-background-repeat: stretch;
}
```

Anyone got any idea on why this is?

P.S. I have already used two different paths to get to the image, both the image file location within my project and the image file location on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

```
.background {
-fx-background-position: center;
-fx-background-color: #BDBDBD;
-fx-background-image: url('file:src/Background.png');
-fx-background-repeat: stretch;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Absolute Path` from IntelliJ IDEA.

For that simply follow the steps:

1. Right click on the image from your IntelliJ IDEA directory.
2. Click on `Copy Path/Reference...`

[image: Copy path/reference in IntelliJ IDEA]

3. Select the `Absolute Path`. Only clicking on that usually copies the link. But you can also `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `C` to copy the path.
   [image: Select the absolute path from IntelliJ IDEA]
4. Now simply paste the absolute path to the `FXML` file in the image source.

[image: Use the absolute path in the FXML file]

5. Make sure to use an additional slash `\` in the directory slashes as it needs to slash to specify that it is part of that address, not any escaping character.

Please keep in mind that these procedures apply only when you have already copied the image file inside the project folder. If you want to use images located in a different directory, then you have to copy the absolute path. If you are using the Windows operating system, you can simply copy the absolute path by right clicking on the image file and going into the properties. The `Location` section contains the path.

If the `Location` does not contain the absolute path including the file name then you simply need to add the file name manually.
For example, check the image below.

[image: Properties of an image from Windows operating system]

Here, in this file's properties tab, the file name is not included in the `Location` section. Therefore, I need to add the filename at the end of the location/path manually.

In this case, my absolute path would be `C:\Users\fahim\Pictures\Screenshots\Screenshot_20230221_110058.png`.

If I want to use this path in the `FXML` file, I need to add one more slash there after each slash in the location. Then the path that I will include in my `FXML` file is this: `C:\\Users\\fahim\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\Screenshot_20230221_110058.png`.

Also, if you do not use any extra slashes ( `\` ), that will also work perfectly!

For example, check the following code.

```
<image>
            <Image url="C:\Users\fahim\Desktop\aoop-uiu\SceneBuilder_01\FirstApp\src\image\background.jpg" />
</image>
```

I did not use any extra slash ( `\` ) in the absolute path now, but it still works like earlier.

[image: Absolute path without any extra slash]